# One query to get multiple, unrelated columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

Say I have 3 tables: table1, table2, and table3. I essentially want to combine the following 3 queries together:

1. `SELECT columnA FROM table1`
2. `SELECT columnB FROM table2`
3. `SELECT columnC FROM table3`

The columns may be of different size, and I want to avoid repeating data. So if columnA has 3 elements, columnB has 1 element, and columnC has 2 elements, I would get a table in which each column has the respective number of elements. Unfilled rows can be left NULL.

**How do I create a single query that accomplishes this task?**

The simple query `SELECT DISTINCT table1.columnA, table2.columnB, table3.columnC FROM table1, table2, table3` just gives me a table of all possible combinations of all the elements within these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the union idea and add in a rownumber you can create a list of rownumbers which you can then use to left join to the three tables. For example

```
drop table if exists t1,t2,t3;
create table t1(id int);
create table t2(id int);
create table t3(id int);

insert into t1 values(1),(3);
insert into t2 values(10),(20),(40);
insert into t3 values(3);


select s.rownumber,t1.id t1id
        ,t2.id t2id
        ,t3.id t3id
from
(
select @r1:=@r1+1 rownumber from t1 cross join(select @r1:=0) r1
union 
select @r2:=@r2+1 rownumber from t2 cross join(select @r2:=0) r2
union 
select @r2:=@r3+1 rownumber from t3 cross join(select @r3:=0) r3
) s
left join (
select id,@r4:=@r4+1 rownumber from t1 cross join(select @r4:=0) r4
) t1 on t1.rownumber = s.rownumber
left join (
select id,@r5:=@r5+1 rownumber from t2 cross join(select @r5:=0) r5
) t2 on t2.rownumber = s.rownumber
left join (
select id,@r6:=@r6+1 rownumber from t3 cross join(select @r6:=0) r6
) t3 on t3.rownumber = s.rownumber
;

+-----------+------+------+------+
| rownumber | t1id | t2id | t3id |
+-----------+------+------+------+
|         1 |    1 |   10 |    3 |
|         2 |    3 |   20 | NULL |
|         3 | NULL |   40 | NULL |
+-----------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this is what I was looking for. Two followup questions:

1. Can you explain the line `@r1:=@r1+1`? I'm having a hard time understanding what it does. I looked up the syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), but it states "The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment."

2. Is there a more scalable way of writing this query? Each additional column takes significant work.

Comment: Update: No need to explain `@r1:=@r1+1`. I think I understand why it works now

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL`  or `UNION` help you. depends on if you want dupplicates or not:

```
SELECT columnA FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT columnB FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT columnC FROM table3
```

For more informations read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

**EDIT:**

You can use a second column with fix text to differentiate the records in your application:

```
SELECT columnA,'TABLE1' FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT columnB,'TABLE2' FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT columnC,'TABLE3' FROM table3
```

Comment: I would like to keep my data in separate columns if possible. The data from the different tables would be used in different parts of my application, and I'm not sure how I would differentiate the data once it's been stacked into one column.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I didn't exactly mark this as the accepted solution, I will probably be using this as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the distinct values you can use  UNION

```
SELECT columnA , 'T1' t_name
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT columnB, 'T2'  
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT columnC , 'T3' 
FROM table3
```

but if you need all the values you should use UNION ALL

```
SELECT columnA, 'T1' t_name
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT columnB, 'T2' 
FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT columnC , 'T3' 
FROM table3
```

Comment: I would like to keep my data in separate columns if possible. The data from the different tables would be used in different parts of my application, and I'm not sure how I would differentiate the data once it's been stacked into one column.

Comment: You could add  a liter value for assign the source table  ..  answer updated .. hope is useful

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I didn't exactly mark this as the accepted solution, I will probably be using this as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using union

```
    SELECT columnA FROM table1
    union
    SELECT columnB FROM table2
    union 
    SELECT columnC FROM table3
```

Comment: I would like to keep my data in separate columns if possible. The data from the different tables would be used in different parts of my application, and I'm not sure how I would differentiate the data once it's been stacked into one column.